# Which usage is correct for the word Rebel?

Tags: grammar, nouns, sentence

Which is the correct version, Rebels Outpost or Rebel Outpost? Doesn't the "s" signify that its multiple rebels? And rebel meaning "To rebel"? Rebel could also be used as plural couldn't it, in third person context?

Used in a sentence. Become part of the Rebels Outpost team or Become part of the Rebel Outpost team.

Comment: If *outpost* is a **verb,** then its subject could be *rebels.* However, I suspect that *outpost* is a noun here with *rebel* an attributive noun (functioning as an adjective), in which case that adjective is not inflected for number.

Comment: So it's perfectly fine to use 'rebels' with the 's' due to it being an attributive noun? 'RebelsOutpost' one word is a brand name. How would it change from let's say adjective 'To Rebel' from multiple 'rebels,' plural?

Comment: No, an attributive noun functions as an adjective, and adjectives are not inflected for number so it must be *rebel* in that case. I've no idea what your last two sentences in your comment are asking, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah, sorry was still editing. What if the name is a brand name of sorts "RebelsOutpost" 
would it still follow the same school of thought?

Comment: Brand names can do whatever you want.